# How to convert DocuSign CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates to CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms?

Tags: docusignapi

How to convert CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates to CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms?

The older method takes an array of docuSignWeb.TemplateReference[] and the newer method CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms takes an array of DocuSignWeb.CompositeTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is create a composite template that is a simple template that includes the original template from your docuSignWeb.TemplateReference[] collection that you used for the call to CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates.
Composite Templates can include a variety of things, one of them is just a regular template which is what you want. See json example below. The serverTemplates is the collection you want and you can just have a single template in there:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Composite Templates",
    "emailBlurb": "Composite Templates Sample 1",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "55A80182-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-FD1E1C0F9D74"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "johndoe@email.com",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Buyer"
                }]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```